# Downloading just part of a file

Tags: http, go, curl

I want to download just part of a text-like file from the internet using go. It appears that curl `--max-filesize` and `--range` aren't respected by the websites I want to download from. Additionally, I read that the http `MaxBytesReader` still downloads the entire file, but only stores part of it.

Is there a way to just get the first kb of a file and then close the connection? The equivalent of pressing "x" when a large page is loading, on chrome.
I'm thinking that I can run a thread that reads a website to a file, and then kill the thread after a ms or two. Is this possible?

Comment: Please share your code, will be better for others  to understand your situation more quickly !

Comment: Well, the issue is that I don't have any code yet. I haven't found a way to implement anything yet, as all of the options do not limit the download size.

Comment: Wrap the body of your http response with an [io.LimitedReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitedReader). This will ensure your read response does not go beyond the limit you set.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it without much error handling (which would have to added could be):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

const readLimit = 1024 // bytes

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
    if err != nil {
       // handle error
    }

    fixedReader := io.LimitedReader{R: resp.Body, N: readLimit}

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(fixedReader)
    resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Comment: When you run http.Get isn't the entire file being sent still?

Comment: It could be, an http header that limits the response size could be added to the request

Comment: Did some testing-- the entire file is still sent, however, just part of it is written

Comment: To reduce the actual response size you’d have to add the HTTP ‘Range: bytes=0-1023’ however it’d be up to the server whether it accepts ranges or not. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Comment: Yeah in the OP i wrote >It appears that curl --max-filesize and --range aren't respected by the websites I want to download from